# Regex: Remove a character before a plus character?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am using Notepad++, and I am looking for a regular expression that can remove every occurrence of a vertical bar character `|` that occurs before a plus `+`, but not after.

Example of a line:

```
290167 275b93| e4dcab59949+k70ba3f31cc63|4d4746bd758ff618afc82556
```

This needs to be:

```
290167 275b93 e4dcab59949+k70ba3f31cc63|4d4746bd758ff618afc82556
```

Here is the regex that I tried to isolate with no result:

```
[|](?<=[+])
```

(Lines contain space characters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track, but your find pattern is slightly off.  Try this version:

```
Find:    [|](?=.*[+])
Replace: (empty string)
```

Here is a working demo:

### Demo

The logic you want here is to find all pipes so long as there is a plus sign which appears later in the string.  The positive lookahead `(?=.*[+])` asserts this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to lookahead for a `+` elsewhere on the line. `(?<=` is lookbehind, you don't want that (lookahead syntax is `(?=`), and there's no need for a character set with a single character:

```
\|(?=[^+\n]*\+)
```

and replace with the empty string.

https://regex101.com/r/MpuWfp/2

Comment: thanks but when I try in notepad++ it finds | also after the + char. (when there are more lines)

Comment: Include `\n` in the negative character set, so that the lookahead doesn't move across linebreaks